# Timer in C# stops firing event after few hours

Tags: c#, .net

I have a code that uses timer. It works nice but after few hours timer stops raising elapsed event:

```
using Timer = System.Timers.Timer;
public void Start()
{
    try
    {
        _timer = new Timer(Configuration.Configuration.MainLoopIntervalMs) {AutoReset = false};
        _timer.Elapsed += Test;
        _timer.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.Error(e, "Exception ");
    }   
}
private void Test(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    try
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Im doing here some more stuff");
    }
    catch(Exception e){ }
    _timer.Stop();
    _timer.Start(); 
}
```

It works like expected for few hours but then `Test` method stops being executed even tohugh console application still runs. What may be the reason for that?

Comment: Did you make sure `_timer` cannot be collected by the garbage collector?

Comment: Also, you set `AutoReset` to `false`, what happens if `//do some work` throws an exception?

Comment: I think that it would be the case with System.Threading Timer not System.Timers Timer :)

Comment: It is in try catch block and there was no exception

Comment: So you have a try/catch block in `Test`?

Comment: You have an *empty* try/catch in `Test`?

Comment: An empty catch block would silently catch all errors, but it would let the code continue to execute and then call `_timer.Start()`, so in respect to restarting the timer it is fine. As a general piece of code, not so much, but that might be a case of simplification for the question.

Comment: An empty catch block only hinders your ability to detect issues in your code.  At a *minimum*, log something.  Otherwise, remove that try/catch entirely.

Comment: You did everything right, except for posting the real code you use.  Which surely just throws an exception over and over again with no way for you to see that.  Can't write this kind of code without a logger.

Answer (score 1):

There are some points you should check.

1. Where is `_timer` defined? Are you sure there is at least one reference hold anywhere in you code so that the garbage collector will never collect it.
2. Make sure `_timer.Start()` is called -> use a `finally` block.
3. Make sure every line of code is inside the `try-catch` scope.
4. `_timer.Stop()` is not necessary because `AutoReset = false` means that after firing `Elapsed` once the timer is stopped.
5. You could register a callback to `_timer.Disposed` to monitor if it gets disposed by some other component in your code (set a breakpoint and wait for it to happen and than look into the call stack): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.component.disposed?view=netframework-4.8
6. Try one of the other timers for example [System.Threading.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer?view=netframework-4.8)
7. Never suppress exceptions with an empty catch clause, at least log something so that you do not fail silently.

```
using Timer = System.Timers.Timer;
public void Start()
{
    try
    {
        _timer = new Timer(Configuration.Configuration.MainLoopIntervalMs) {AutoReset = false};
        _timer.Elapsed += Test;
        _timer.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _logger.Error(e, "Exception ");
    }   
}

private void Test(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs eventArgs)
{
   // No code outside try-catch
   try
   {
       _logger.Debug("Test - Start");
       // Do all your work
       Console.WriteLine("Im doing here some more stuff");
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
       _logger.Error(e, "Some usefull description")
   }
   finally
   {
       _timer.Start();
       _logger.Debug("_timer restarted"); 
   }
}
```